# Issues with creating an individual chat between admin and each logged in user

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, chat, decoding

This is my main dart, sending data to Firebase

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:my_chat/screens/welcome_screen.dart';
    import 'package:my_chat/screens/login_screen.dart';
    import 'package:my_chat/screens/registration_screen.dart';
    import 'package:my_chat/screens/chat_screen.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
    
    void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      runApp(FlashChat());
    }
```

Here I want to add route to adminpage

```
    class FlashChat extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          initialRoute: WelcomeScreen.id,
          routes: {
            WelcomeScreen.id: (context) => WelcomeScreen(),
            LoginScreen.id: (context) => LoginScreen(),
            RegistrationScreen.id: (context) => RegistrationScreen(),
            ChatScreen.id: (context) => ChatScreen(),
          },
        );
      }
    }`
```

This is my login screen, in this screen I want to login as admin and chat with users one to one

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_chat/components/rounded_button.dart';
import 'package:my_chat/constants.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:my_chat/screens/chat_screen.dart';
import 'package:modal_progress_hud_nsn/modal_progress_hud_nsn.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'login_screen';
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool showSpinner = false;
  late String email;
  late String password;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: ModalProgressHUD(
        inAsyncCall: showSpinner,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: Hero(
                  tag: 'logo',
                  child: Container(
                    height: 200.0,
                    child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 48.0,
              ),
              TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  email = value;
                },
                decoration:
                    kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Enter your email'),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 8.0,
              ),
              TextField(
                obscureText: true,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  password = value;
                },
                decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                    hintText: 'Enter your Password'),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 24.0,
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: RoundedButton(
                  text: 'Log In',
                  onPressed: () async {
                    try {
                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = true;
                      });
                      final user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                          email: email, password: password);
                      if (user != null) {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
                      }
                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = false;
                      });
                    } catch (e) {
                      print(e);
                    }
                  },
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my welcome screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_chat/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:my_chat/screens/registration_screen.dart';
import 'package:animated_text_kit/animated_text_kit.dart';
import 'package:my_chat/components/rounded_button.dart';

class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'welcome_screen';
  @override
  _WelcomeScreenState createState() => _WelcomeScreenState();
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;
  late Animation animation;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
    animation = ColorTween(begin: Colors.blueGrey, end: Colors.white)
        .animate(controller);
    controller.forward();
    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: animation.value,
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  child: Hero(
                    tag: 'logo',
                    child: Container(
                      child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
                      height: 60.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                DefaultTextStyle(
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 45.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                    color: Colors.black45,
                  ),
                  child: AnimatedTextKit(
                    animatedTexts: [TypewriterAnimatedText('Flash Chat')],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 48.0,
            ),
            RoundedButton(
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                text: 'Log In',
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.id);
                }),
            RoundedButton(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              text: 'Register',
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, RegistrationScreen.id);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my chat screen, here I want to chat only with admin, users should chat with admin only.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_chat/constants.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

final _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
late User loggedInUser;

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'chat_screen';
  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final messageTextController = TextEditingController();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  late String messageText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                _auth.signOut();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
        ],
        title: Text('⚡️Chat'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            MessagesStream(),
            Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: messageTextController,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        messageText = value;
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      messageTextController.clear();
                      _fireStore.collection('messages').add({
                        'text': messageText,
                        'sender': loggedInUser.email,
                        'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
  const MessagesStream({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _fireStore
          .collection('messages')
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: false)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        }
        final messages = (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs.reversed;
        List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messageText = message.get('text');
          final messageSender = message.get('sender');
          final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;
          final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
            sender: messageSender,
            text: messageText,
            isMe: currentUser == messageSender,
          );
          messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            reverse: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
            children: messageBubbles,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  const MessageBubble({
    Key? key,
    required this.sender,
    required this.text,
    this.isMe,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String sender;
  final String text;
  final bool? isMe;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment:
            isMe == true ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            sender,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12.0,
              color: Colors.black54,
            ),
          ),
          Material(
            borderRadius: isMe == true
                ? BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0))
                : BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0)),
            elevation: 5.0,
            color: isMe == true ? Colors.lightBlueAccent : Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 10.0,
                horizontal: 20.0,
              ),
              child: Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: isMe == true ? Colors.white : Colors.black54,
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If someone has any idea, please help me. Full code source is at https://github.com/Daulenazar/Chat-with-admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack overflow is generally used to get answers to specific questions, and less for general design/architecture advice.

With that being said, here are some resources to help you:

- Jeff Delaney (Google Developer Expert) has a youtube channel called Fireship which discusses various tools and how to use them. He also has a flutter firebase course on [his website](https://fireship.io/courses/flutter-firebase/).
- The Flutter and Firebase teams have examples for how to use Firestore in FLutter on [their website](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/example/)
- Firebase has the ability to lock down the database to allow CRUD operations for specific users with `Custom Claims`. See the docs [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access).

Lastly, from my own perspective it sounds like you want to create a role based authentication chat app. You can save permissions for different users on the user document.

For example, a non admin user can have a Document like this

Firestore Collection: `users/<Their Firebase Authentication ID>`

```js
{
 email: 'joe@soap.com',
 permissions: {
  admin: false
   }
}
```

And your own document:

`users/<Your Firebase Authentication ID>`

```js
{
 email: 'Daulet@someDomain.com',
 permissions: {
  admin: true
   }
}
```

In the UI you can read the logged in users document from firestore and only show certain pages or allow certain actions if the logged in user has the `permissions.admin` property set to `true`.

There are many ways to go about this but I recommend checking out the [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs) and Youtube tutorials.